# why can't I access my postgres from remote?

Tags: postgresql, timeout, remote-access

I have a Postgres 10.3 Server installed on an Ubuntu Server.

I did the necessary settings, which always had been enough to be able to access it from PGAdmin from my Laptop, but this time it doesn't work.

I tried the following steps:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
ufw allow 5432
Postgresql restarted
Server rebooted
Server pinged with success
Restarted the VPN-Client
direct IP instead of VPN-IP
disabled IPTABLES
```

Locally I can connect to the server, but remote is still not working.

When I try to connect, it doesn't seem, that postgres is blocking it, but something before:

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
Is the server running on host "10.8.0.50" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: That error means that the TCP communication between the machines is not working properly. It might be a firewall that drops packets.

Comment: iptables is not "turned on" and on sfw i did allow it ... is there another firewall i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the server were set up, Plesk were installed.

Plesk had an own firewall, which denied the connection. After allowing it, it worked flawless.